# Classic ASP (VBScript) convert HTML codes to plain text

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to convert HTML Codes like the &#XXXX; (where XXXX is a number) to plain text using classic ASP (VBScript).

I'm adding the text to an email which is in plain text format and if I add them as HTML Codes, it just displays the code and doesn't convert them.

One fix would be to change the email to be HTML which does fix that problem but then causes other problems for my email which I won't go into.

Is there a built in function or a custom function I can use to convert these HTML Codes to plain text?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you need is HTML Decode, though unfortunately ASP doesn't include one.

This function, found on [ASP Nut](http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp), and modified heavily by me, should do what you need.  I tested it as vbscript running on my local computer and it seemed to work well, even with Unicode symbols in the 1000+ range.

```
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim regEx
    Dim matches
    Dim match
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))


    Set regEx= New RegExp

    With regEx
     .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes
     .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText)

    'Iterate over matches
    For Each match in matches
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits.

        sText = Replace(sText, match.Value, ChrW(match.SubMatches(0)))
    Next

    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```

<sub>Note: You'll need script version 5.0 installed on your server to use the RegExp object.</sub>

Comment: Already tried that one, the HTML Codes that I'm using are for Arabic letters so the codes are something like &#1600; which obviously isn't covered by the for 1 to 255.

Comment: @Scrooby and `Chr` doesn't support things in that range ... a little searching indicates that the `ChrW` function does what you want with unicode.

Comment: Thanks for function, I'm having a few problems with it though. When I try and decode one of the arabic letters, for example &#1575; it just returns a question mark. I'm guessing it's something to do with my page charset, although my page is set to ISO-8859-6 as is the form I'm trying to use the value in.

Comment: hmm, ok. As an alternative, do you know of a VBScript function that can ENCODE arabic text to make it HTML Code characters?

Comment: @Scrooby I can work that out, can you make it a new question, because we're pretty far afield.  We can also chat about it [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/833/asp-classic-and-other-evils).

Comment: Thanks, I've added a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124939/convert-arabic-text-to-html-code-characters

Comment: For longer numerical entities, `ChrW` may not cope. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161304/11683.

Answer (score 4):

A more exausted decoder epanding C. Ross response

```
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim regEx
    Dim matches
    Dim match
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))

    sText = Replace(sText, "&iexcl;", Chr(161))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&pound;", Chr(163))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&yen;", Chr(165))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&copy;", Chr(168))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&laquo;", Chr(171))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&raquo;", Chr(187))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&iquest;", Chr(191))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Agrave;", Chr(192))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Aacute;", Chr(193))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Acirc;", Chr(194))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Atilde;", Chr(195))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Auml;", Chr(196))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Aring;", Chr(197))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&AElig;", Chr(198))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ccedil;", Chr(199))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Egrave;", Chr(200))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Eacute;", Chr(201))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ecirc;", Chr(202))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Euml;", Chr(203))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Igrave;", Chr(204))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Iacute;", Chr(205))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Icirc;", Chr(206))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Iuml;", Chr(207))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ntilde;", Chr(209))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ograve;", Chr(210))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Oacute;", Chr(211))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ocirc;", Chr(212))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Otilde;", Chr(213))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ouml;", Chr(214))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&times;", Chr(215))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Oslash;", Chr(216))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ugrave;", Chr(217))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Uacute;", Chr(218))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Ucirc;", Chr(219))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Uuml;", Chr(220))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&Yacute;", Chr(221))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&THORN;", Chr(222))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&szlig;", Chr(223))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&agrave;", Chr(224))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&aacute;", Chr(225))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&acirc;", Chr(226))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&atilde;", Chr(227))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&auml;", Chr(228))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&aring;", Chr(229))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&aelig;", Chr(230))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ccedil;", Chr(231))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&egrave;", Chr(232))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&eacute;", Chr(233))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ecirc;", Chr(234))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&euml;", Chr(235))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&igrave;", Chr(236))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&iacute;", Chr(237))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&icirc;", Chr(238))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&iuml;", Chr(239))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&eth;", Chr(240))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ntilde;", Chr(241))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ograve;", Chr(242))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&oacute;", Chr(243))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ocirc;", Chr(244))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&otilde;", Chr(245))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ouml;", Chr(246))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&divide;", Chr(247))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&oslash;", Chr(248))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ugrave;", Chr(249))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&uacute;", Chr(250))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&ucirc;", Chr(251))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&uuml;", Chr(252))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&yacute;", Chr(253))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&thorn;", Chr(254))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&yuml;", Chr(255))

    Set regEx= New RegExp

    With regEx
     .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes
     .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText)

    'Iterate over matches
    For Each match in matches
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits.

        sText = Replace(sText, match.Value, ChrW(match.SubMatches(0)))
    Next

    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this based on C.Ross's answer above and some code from a fb_app.inc someone else made. It should do the trick.

```
    <%
    Option Explicit

    Dim objHelper
    Set objHelper = New HtmlEntityToUnicode

    Response.Write(objHelper.HtmlDecode("<br/><br/>hi  &#128154; green heart! purple heart &#128156; ! "))

    Set objHelper = Nothing

    Class HtmlEntityToUnicode
    dim BITS_TO_A_BYTE 
    dim BYTES_TO_A_WORD 
    dim BITS_TO_A_WORD 
    Dim m_lOnBits(30)
    Dim m_l2Power(30)

    Sub Class_Initialize()


        BITS_TO_A_BYTE = 8
        BYTES_TO_A_WORD = 4
        BITS_TO_A_WORD = 32

        m_lOnBits(0) = CLng(1)
        m_lOnBits(1) = CLng(3)
        m_lOnBits(2) = CLng(7)
        m_lOnBits(3) = CLng(15)
        m_lOnBits(4) = CLng(31)
        m_lOnBits(5) = CLng(63)
        m_lOnBits(6) = CLng(127)
        m_lOnBits(7) = CLng(255)
        m_lOnBits(8) = CLng(511)
        m_lOnBits(9) = CLng(1023)
        m_lOnBits(10) = CLng(2047)
        m_lOnBits(11) = CLng(4095)
        m_lOnBits(12) = CLng(8191)
        m_lOnBits(13) = CLng(16383)
        m_lOnBits(14) = CLng(32767)
        m_lOnBits(15) = CLng(65535)
        m_lOnBits(16) = CLng(131071)
        m_lOnBits(17) = CLng(262143)
        m_lOnBits(18) = CLng(524287)
        m_lOnBits(19) = CLng(1048575)
        m_lOnBits(20) = CLng(2097151)
        m_lOnBits(21) = CLng(4194303)
        m_lOnBits(22) = CLng(8388607)
        m_lOnBits(23) = CLng(16777215)
        m_lOnBits(24) = CLng(33554431)
        m_lOnBits(25) = CLng(67108863)
        m_lOnBits(26) = CLng(134217727)
        m_lOnBits(27) = CLng(268435455)
        m_lOnBits(28) = CLng(536870911)
        m_lOnBits(29) = CLng(1073741823)
        m_lOnBits(30) = CLng(2147483647)

        m_l2Power(0) = CLng(1)
        m_l2Power(1) = CLng(2)
        m_l2Power(2) = CLng(4)
        m_l2Power(3) = CLng(8)
        m_l2Power(4) = CLng(16)
        m_l2Power(5) = CLng(32)
        m_l2Power(6) = CLng(64)
        m_l2Power(7) = CLng(128)
        m_l2Power(8) = CLng(256)
        m_l2Power(9) = CLng(512)
        m_l2Power(10) = CLng(1024)
        m_l2Power(11) = CLng(2048)
        m_l2Power(12) = CLng(4096)
        m_l2Power(13) = CLng(8192)
        m_l2Power(14) = CLng(16384)
        m_l2Power(15) = CLng(32768)
        m_l2Power(16) = CLng(65536)
        m_l2Power(17) = CLng(131072)
        m_l2Power(18) = CLng(262144)
        m_l2Power(19) = CLng(524288)
        m_l2Power(20) = CLng(1048576)
        m_l2Power(21) = CLng(2097152)
        m_l2Power(22) = CLng(4194304)
        m_l2Power(23) = CLng(8388608)
        m_l2Power(24) = CLng(16777216)
        m_l2Power(25) = CLng(33554432)
        m_l2Power(26) = CLng(67108864)
        m_l2Power(27) = CLng(134217728)
        m_l2Power(28) = CLng(268435456)
        m_l2Power(29) = CLng(536870912)
        m_l2Power(30) = CLng(1073741824)

    End Sub

    Public Function HTMLDecode(sText)
        Dim regEx
        Dim matches
        Dim match
        sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
        sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
        sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
        sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
        sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))


        Set regEx= New RegExp

        With regEx
         .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes
         .Global = True
        End With

        Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText)

        'Iterate over matches
        For Each match in matches
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits.
            sText = Replace(sText, match.Value, "\U"&WordToHex(match.SubMatches(0)))
        Next

        HTMLDecode = sText
    End Function


    Private Function WordToHex(lValue)
        Dim lByte
        Dim lCount

        For lCount = 0 To 3
            lByte = RShift(lValue, lCount * BITS_TO_A_BYTE) And m_lOnBits(BITS_TO_A_BYTE - 1)
             WordToHex = Right("0" & Hex(lByte), 2) & WordToHex 
        Next
    End Function

    Private Function RShift(lValue, iShiftBits)
        If iShiftBits = 0 Then
            RShift = lValue
            Exit Function
        ElseIf iShiftBits = 31 Then
            If lValue And &H80000000 Then
                RShift = 1
            Else
                RShift = 0
            End If
            Exit Function
        ElseIf iShiftBits < 0 Or iShiftBits > 31 Then
            Err.Raise 6
        End If

        RShift = (lValue And &H7FFFFFFE) \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits)

        If (lValue And &H80000000) Then
            RShift = (RShift Or (&H40000000 \ m_l2Power(iShiftBits - 1)))
        End If
    End Function

    End Class


    %>
```