# Print out HTML email in plain text into browser in Classic ASP

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to see what markup my HTML email has inside of it. So I want to print out:

> **Order Confirmation Email**

As HTML tags onto the page like so:

```
<b>Order Confirmation Email</b>
```

How can I achieve this in Classic ASP (VBScript)? I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115708/classic-asp-vbscript-convert-html-codes-to-plain-text) and used the function mentioned on there, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Server.HTMLEncode(string)

```
<%
 response.write(Server.HTMLEncode("The image tag: <img>"))
%>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp