# How to remove amp; from URL

Tags: vbscript, url-encoding, urldecode

I am getting a URL that contains `amp;`. Is there any way to remove this as currently I tried `URLDecode` function, but It's not working. Do I need to remove It using simple string replacement or Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can you perhaps show the URL *(just with the hostname changed)*?

Comment: https://example.com?xyz=1&amp;ID=6184&amp;KEY=6e8a64fc-1c1e-11e6-9059-b97210fab7z6

Comment: You shouldn't have `&amp;` in there in the first place, they are HTML encoded entities which is why `URLDecode()` won't work. If it was URL encoded it would be `%3D` not `&amp;`. You want to look at why the URL is coming through like that I guess somewhere someone has used `HTMLEncode()` in error.

Comment: Well thanks however I can't ask my client for any change so I have to manage at my own end therefor Is there any better way to solve this?

Comment: If it's HTML encoded then you need to decode it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6116611/692942 or if it's just the `&amp;` that is encoded use something like `url = Replace(url, "amp;", "")`, but you when have to `Response.Redirect()` *(assuming your using ASP)* to re-run the page with the correct parameters. The issue is the clients it should be them making sure they pass you a correctly formed URL.

Comment: Can you just replace those out: `url=Replace(url, "amp;", "")`

Comment: @JNevill It depends if the client sent the URL incorrect it's already to late, unless you parse the URL *(using `Replace()` or whatever)* and re-run the request *(be it `Response.Redirect()` or `ServerHTTPRequest.Send()`)*.

Comment: Sorry @Lankymart. I didn't see your suggestion `replace()` right before my comment. :/ Not paying attention this morning.

Comment: @JNevill I was mid edit when your comment came through, no apology needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300806/how-to-remove-amp-from-url-in-vbscript#comment62124119_37300806) pointed out `URLDecode` only works on [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding) characters (`%26`), not on [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) (`&amp;`). Use a regular [string replacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to change the HTML entity `&amp;` into a literal ampersand:

```vb
url = Replace(url, "&amp;", "&")
```

Comment: What will that do though if the URL has already been received from the client? At some point the OP will have to "re-run" the request after the URL has been stripped of `&amp;` I guess.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to even speculate about where the URL came from or what he's going to do with it, so I just answered the immediate question (or rather made the comments into an actual answer).

Comment: See your point, but OP did [kind of confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300806/how-to-remove-amp-from-url/37301978?noredirect=1#comment62124271_37300806) they are not in control of the URL they receive.

Comment: Still, without him showing (some of) his code and/or explaining what he's trying to accomplish we'd merely be speculating, and I prefer not to do that. As soon as there's more information everyone is free to post a better answer (or improve this one, since I posted it as a wiki answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Angular I added amp; to the params names

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.user_id = params['user_id'];
  this.practice_id = params['amp;practice_id'];
  this.patient_id = params['amp;patient_id'];
});
```