# Detecting a specific Unicode text in an Excel cell from an array of possiblilities

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I use VBA to format my spreadsheets. The units have their own format.

How do I detect the ohm symbol? (According to character map = U+03A9)

[image: Extract from a typical sheet]

I can write it as R, or as "ohm", but is there was a method of the level

```
if left(string,1) = something here then
```

An added complication is that I use arrays made up of strings from a single string and the SPLIT command, like this.

```
LIST = " m mm mpm m/min s Pa kg N Nm mm/s Hz rpm GBP ul rad/s N/mm perc PC rev/s MPa psi N/mm2 mm2 "
WrdArray() = Split(LIST, " ")
```

Then I compare the cell with each member of the array.

I thought of concatenating the unicode chars into this string, but then the whole thing would need to be a different string type, wouldn't it?

I am familiar with VBA but unicode chars, when the IDE does not seem to support them well, are a challenge.

---

I just tried Ike's suggestion below and got this (in yellow), which is fantastic.

Correct formatting result for Unicode characters
[image]

The entering the symbols in the list was exactly as Ike said. Note here I am also adding a hybrid for the microFarad unit.

```
LIST_TAG2 = " " & ChrW(8486) & " " & ChrW(937) & " " & ChrW(&HB5) & "F "
```

Oddly though, the original routine to detect matches seems to still work.
ss is a string variable which is the cell text.

```vb
WrdArray4() = Split(UCase(LIST_TAG2), " ")

For jj = LBound(WrdArray4) To UBound(WrdArray4)
    If WrdArray4(jj) = UCase(Trim(ss)) Then
        CELL_TYPE = IS_TAG2
        B = True
    End If
Next jj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check a certain cell value (e.g. selected cell) for the Ω-character use `If AscW(selection) = 8486 ...`

Regarding your list: You have to add the Ω-character as `LIST = ChrW(8486) & " m mm "` as you can't type it in the VBE editor.

Comment: As the OP mentions U+03A9 (which is 937 decimal), I assume it should be ChrW(937) which gives the greek Capital Omega.

Comment: Hmm - if you search for "unicode ohm" xou get the code I used - but indeed in Excel both results look very similar

Comment: I just googled "Ohm" and copied the displayed character from the top of the page into Excel - it was ChrW(937) - was just about to type my answer when I  saw yours. Was surprised that you found a different character.

Comment: Fyi Further readings: [Get Unicode characters with charcode greater hex FFFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008191/get-unicode-characters-with-charcode-values-greater-hex-ffff) and [Alternative of `ChrW` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158679/alternative-of-chrw-function)

Comment: Thank you to all three of you for this comprehensive answer. Well spotted by FunThomas about the second ohm sign, and they do seem to be identical so both would need to be searched for. Also for T.M.s extra part for really high value Unicode. Ike's answer has solved the problem in a simple way. Thanks again to all of you.